# joomla! + roksprocket multilanguage issue

Tags: javascript, joomla, module, multilingual

Hi and thanks in advance for any help.

I'm working on a multilanguage joomla! website that runs some roksprocket mosaic modules positioned right after single article content.

When I navigate the site by using the default language everything works great, but when I switch to a non-default language I experience URL problems with content loaded inside the roksprocket module by the "load more" button or by the filtering tags.
The first block of visible items, loaded with the page, link to the correct articles. But when I filter the items or click the load more button, the new loaded articles links are not working. Default language tags are automatically added to the url of the links. So I get:

`www.mysiteurl.com/default_language_tag/alias_of_the_current_page_tag/category_tag/article_tag`

This happens both with and without SEF URLS activated.

I would try to avoid these added tags by cutting them out from the html with javascript, but I don't know what is triggered after the loading of the new content.
Any suggestion?

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Are you using built in Joomla for translating or a 3rd party component?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. I solved the problem by switching "Remove URL Language Code" to "yes" in the System - Language Filter plugin basic options. Then everything worked great.